# Mac connect to ubuntu vps ovh

Tags: macos, vps

How can i connect to my ovh vps server from Osx ?

I've tried to connect using Chicken of the VNC, but connection failed.
Does any ovh vps servers have remote desktop connection available ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: at the moment, i connect using terminal, and every script i start to run are closed when i close my terminal. That's a little problem for me.. i need to run my server from my vps to keep it connected without my own computer..will be better :p !

Answer (score 0):

first you can detach your script from your terminal : run them in background (&) with nohup from a bash term launched into your initial session when you close your session your scripts will be attached to init
`$ bash
$ nohup my_command &
$ exit`

second part of the question
Chicken is not a term ???
What do you want to do ?
If you want to launch GUI programs use ssh -X and setup X11 both on your mac and your server (there are many posts about this)